# Таймаут для чтения из SSL-сокета приостанавливается, когда экран выключен

Tags: java, android, сокет, ssl

Я установил таймаут для чтения из `SSLSocket` 2 минуты. Но `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` не приходит, когда экран телефона выключен. Когда я включаю экран, таймаут начинает работать. Это код метода `recieve`:

```
public byte[] recieve() {

    byte[] result = null;

    try {
       ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
       mSocket.setSoTimeout(120000);
       InputStream socketOutStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
       Log.d("xxx", "Waiting response's length...");
       socketOutStream.read(bb.array(), 0, 4);
       int length = bb.getInt();
       Log.d("xxx", String.format("  Response length: %d bytes", length));
       result = new byte[length];
       Log.d("xxx", String.format("Waiting response..", length));
       int bytesRead = socketOutStream.read(result);
       if (bytesRead == length) {
          Log.d("xxx", String.format("  Bytes actually read: %d", length));
          return result;
       }
       else if (bytesRead != 0 && bytesRead < length) {
          length -= bytesRead;
          while (length > 0) {
             int bytesActuallyRead = socketOutStream.read(result, bytesRead, length);
             length -= bytesActuallyRead;
             bytesRead += bytesActuallyRead;
          }
          return result;
       }
    } catch(IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       Log.e("xxx", String.format("Socket error: %s", e.getMessage()));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Мое приложение должно работать, когда экран выключен. Насколько я понимаю, метод `read` у `InputStream` блокирующий. Как я могу решить проблему?

Comment: Проблема блокировки решается созданием отдельного потока под это дело.

Comment: Проблема не в блокировке, работа с сокетами и так в отдельном потоке. Проблема в том, что таймаут на read из InputStream должен работать даже когда отключен экран телефона